# Como enviar ID gravado em variável no retorno JSon

Tags: php, json

Estou fazendo um `insert` usando uma classe mas não estou conseguindo resgatar o último `id` cadastrado, preciso guardar esse id em uma variável no retorno `json` pois preciso dela para fazer um novo cadastro, o que tenho é isso:

```
require_once "../_classes/conexao_pdo.class.php";
require_once "../_classes/crud.class.php";

// Atribui uma conexão PDO   
$pdo = Conexao::getInstance();
$crud = Crud::getInstance($pdo, 'dvsMalote');

// INSERT
$crud = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO dvsMalote ( NumeroBolsa, IdUnicoopRemetente, IdUnicoopDestinatario, DataHoraEnvio, IdUsuarioEnvio, Estado  ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$crud->bindParam(1, $Bolsa, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$crud->bindParam(2, $UnicoopRemetente , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$crud->bindParam(3, $UnicoopDestinatario , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$crud->bindParam(4, $DataHoraEnvio , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$crud->bindParam(5, $Matricula , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$crud->bindParam(6, $Estado , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$retorno = $crud->execute();    

// RECUPERANDO NumeroMalote
$mensId = $pdo->lastInsertId(); 

if ($retorno):
    $retorno = array('codigo' => 1, 'mensagem' => ' Registro inserido com sucesso');
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
else:
    $retorno = array('codigo' => 0, 'mensagem' => ' Erro ao inserir o registro' );
    echo json_encode($retorno);
    exit();
endif;
```

Já consigo recuperar o `id`, agora não sei como enviar esse valor para a página de chamada, a página de chamada que espera a mensagem de retorno está assim:

```
if (response.codigo == "1") {
    $("#msgInsert").html('×AVISO!  ' + response.mensagem  + '');
} else {
    $("#msgInsert").html('×ATENÇÃO!  ' + response.mensagem + '');
}
```

Como posso enviar esse `id` recuperado até ela e posicionar o valor em uma variável?

Comment: Em teoria é isso aí, pode colocar o código do método `insert()`? O id é auto increment certo?

Comment: Olá @rray, obrigado por me dar um toque sobre o insert, fiz uma edição na minha pergunta, agora consigo resgatar o ID mas preciso envia-lo a página de chamada, ou seja, no retorno.

Comment: Lembre que php envia apenas texto para o javascript, logo para transforma ele em um objeto use `var r = JSON.parse(response);` Depois pode fazer algo como `console.log(r.mensagem);`